# How to write a sql query for different conditions in where clause on demand?

Tags: sql-server

I have to pass different parameters as columns from code behind, so i written 15 gridview binding methods for 15 columns, so to avoid this i like to set in query.For example if my column 1 then pick this where clause and if column 2 then pick this where clause.So how to write like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you would create and run dynamic queries

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_search
    @param1         int = NULL,
    @param2         int = NULL
AS
BEGIN    
DECLARE @query_string nvarchar(4000);
SET @query_string = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 1 = 1 ';

        IF(@param1 IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @query_string = @query_string + ' AND columnName1 = ' + CAST(@param1 AS VARCHAR);
        END

        IF(@param2 IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @query_string = @query_string + ' AND columnName2 = ' + CAST(@param2 AS VARCHAR);
        END

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query_string;
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Its just a 'true' to add where clause, because where expects an expression and we cant do it in every if. So to avoid this we add where 1=1. It will not give any error. Just try a query with where 1=1

Comment: Its just an example @marc_s

Comment: ....*and we'll fix it for production release* - yeah right - just ***don't use that prefix - EVER!***

Comment: Or in other words 'where 1 =1' is equivalent expression to a query without 'where 1=1' clause

Comment: Iam passing column name and its value then on that basis have to set condition,then how?

Comment: below is my sql query

Comment: I cant input here stackoverflow throwing an error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Comment: i am sending from codebehind side ddlCoulumn.selectedvalue and ddlcoulumnvalue.selected value and ddlStatus.selected value to storeprocedure then on different conditions selecting coulmns i.e, like where C_Register.AccountExpiry= Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate And C_Register.'+ @ColumnName +' = '+@Value

Comment: Its absolutely error free, properly idented. Just put proper table and column names and it will work

Comment: @abbasazaad you are creating string wrong. Its not my approach but rather your method of passing dynamic parameters